# How to show that $X=(X_1,...,X_p)'$ follows multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_i = \mu_i + \sqrt{1-\rho} Z_i +\sqrt{\rho }Z_0,i=1,...,p,$ for some $\rho >0$, where $Z_i,i=0,1,...,p$, are iid as $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Find the distribution of $X=(X_1,...,X_p)'$

My attempt: I can show that each $X_i, i=1,...,p$ is normal distribution with $N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$.

I can also show that $Cov(X_i, X_j) = \rho \sigma^2$

But I don't know how to show that $X=(X_1,...,X_p)'$ follows multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Your covariance expression is wrong, the diagonal elements are different. What's the definition of the multivariate normal distribution that you're using?

Comment: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R^p$. Then (with some abuse of notation) $$\alpha^T X = \alpha^T(\mu+\sqrt{1-\rho}Z+\sqrt\rho Z_0)  $$, which is gaussian since $(Z_0,Z)$ is a gaussian vector.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed I expect $Cov(X_i, X_j) = \rho \sigma^2$ is only for $i\not=j$.  When $i=j$ you get  $Cov(X_i, X_i) = Var(X_i)= \sigma^2$

Comment: Hint: Write $X = AZ + \mu$ for some matrix $A$ and use the property of the multivariate normal that it is closed under affine transformations.

Comment: @Stefan any matrix A? Is there any reference website?

Comment: You can figure out the matrix by looking at the defining equation of $X_i$ - here it is of course a specific matrix.

Comment: @Stefan A follow-up question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774386/using-helmerts-matrix-to-find-the-density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of [Multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution): *a random vector is said to be k-variate normally distributed if every linear combination of its k components has a univariate normal distribution*.

And it's true that for all $(\alpha_i)_{i=1,..,p}$, we have
$\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i X_i$ follows a normal distribution.

Comment: Small nitpick: this is not the usual definition of the multivariate normal as it requires some proof (this is the Cramer Wold device).

Comment: @Stefan Sorry but it's strange to say: a "not-usual definition" is not a definition. And besides, why did you say "the first definition in the page I mentionned is not a usual definition"?

Comment: Sorry - I should not comment on MSE questions before my first coffee. You are correct :)

Comment: Thank you. A follow-up question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774386/using-helmerts-matrix-to-find-the-density